# `libvirtd` crashes the system

Tags: libvirt, crash, pci-passthrough

Short version:

Using `systemctl start libvirtd` (or `libvirtd.service`, seems to have the same effect?) crashes the system, without warning, if one of the pools has `/dev` allocated.

Long version:

I'm trying install a guest OS with the help of passthrough, on Archlinux, with `virt-manager`. I'm following [this guide](https://dividebyzer0.gitlab.io/GPUpassthrough.html). In the [*Configuring Virtual Machine*](https://dividebyzer0.gitlab.io/GPUpassthrough.html#configuring-virtual-machine) section, the first step is to add storage, and select  the `/dev`. Once I do that, the system will reboot instantly, without any warning, after ~1 min. I have checked with `systemctl status libvirtd` at regular intervals, and the lowest time I got to see was 55 sec; I never got to see 1 min. The setting is saved in `/etc/libvirt/storage/pool*.xml` (`pool-1.xml`, or something like that). I deleted it in the meantime and now there are no more crashes. There are [one](https://old.reddit.com/r/archlinux/comments/o8wy6w/libvirt_reboots_system_after_1_minute/) and [two](https://old.reddit.com/r/archlinux/comments/mbdjot/system_automatically_reboots_1_min_after_booting/) threads on reddit, but none has any workaround.

Is this a known behaviour, or is it a quirk? How do I get around it and finish installing the guest OS?

Comment: What bothers me most is that it resets the system. I would understand if the service would crash, that the programs relying on it might crash (such as `virt-manager`), but why does it hard-reset the computer?

Comment: What devices did you pass through? What storage devices did you specify?

Comment: You're allowing your guest OS to access hardware that has hardware DMA access, and access to the PCIe bus itself, on a system that might have an imperfect IOMMU implementation and with sometimes really strangely behaving PCIe devices. There's very many ways this can go wrong!

Comment: @MarcusMüller I have a 3700x + B450 Tomahawk Max, using 5700xt (guest) + 750Ti (host) (and 32 GB RAM), and I'm following [this guide](https://dividebyzer0.gitlab.io/GPUpassthrough.html) (very similar setup). I doubt it's a matter of mismatch or imperfections (though since I'm not the manufacturer, I can't exclude them, either). It all happens when I reach the 1st step in the "Configuring Virtual Machine" section.

Comment: it definitely is the reason. If starting a VM resets the host, then a device you allowed your VM to control leads to a hardware reset.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Yes, but if I delete the setting holding the `/dev` pool, nothing happens, it works normally (as it does without that setting). So I would say it's something related to the `/dev` that `libvirtd` doesn't like. At any rate, I just received an advice to avoid passing `/dev` or `/dev/sdXX` and use the `qcow2` file format.

Comment: I don't understand what a "`/dev` pool" is?

Comment: Ah I see your guide is a bit strange, OK: You don't add a "dir" storage pool to give a VM direct access to a device file... That is *very* backwards. You select "create new storage pool", and there the type `Disk: Physical Disk Device`

Comment: @MarcusMüller I found the answer, added it below. It's been quite the bumpy ride, this. I wonder what will be next?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turns out I misunderstood the guide. In there, it says to select `/dev/sdb` (which is what I have), not `/dev/sdb2` (which is what I thought, I only wanted that partition). There's a [similar problem here](https://askubuntu.com/q/927574) (on askubuntu, and I also posted this [here](https://forum.level1techs.com/t/libvirtd-reboots-the-system-after-1-min/179497), on level1techs). Once I do that, it works (as backwards as it may be), and I can also add external partitions to be seen from within the guest OS.

Even so, I'd say it's a problem if it resets the system. The service should crash, go bananas, start knitting, drag other denendent programs after it, but not crash the system.